# Python with lot of thread

Tags: python, multithreading, function

I create 4 functions with a different variable,
and I start them with 4 thread,
I want to know how to do to change only the variables of my function and not create a function for each thread.

```
import webbrowser
import urllib.request
import re
import sys
import threading
from threading import Thread

print("donne les 2 premier octets ")
r = input(str(":"))
i = 0
x = 1
"""
--------------------------------------------------------
------------------------Thread 1------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
"""
def f1(x,i,r):
    while i < 64:
            i += 1
            y = str(x)
            u0 = str(i)
            try:
                t0 = urllib.request.urlopen('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0, timeout=1).getcode()
            except:
                t0 = 'http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0+' ---NOP---'
                print(t0)
            if t0 == 200:
                print('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0+' ---OUI---')
                #webbrowser.open('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u)
                url = 'http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0
                req = urllib.request.Request(url)
                resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
                respData = resp.read()
                Title = re.findall(r'e>(.*?)</title>',str(respData))
                Title = str(Title)
                print(Title)
                print('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0+' ---'+Title+'---', file=open("outpute.txt", "a"))
            if i == 64:
                i = 0
                x += 1
"""
--------------------------------------------------------
------------------------Thread 2------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
"""
def f2(x,i,r):
    while i < 64:
                i += 1
                y = str(x)
                u0 = str(i+64)
                try:
                    t0 = urllib.request.urlopen('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0, timeout=1).getcode()
                except:
                    t0 = 'http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0+' ---NOP---'
                    print(t0)
                if t0 == 200:
                    print('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0+' ---OUI---')
                    #webbrowser.open('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u)
                    url = 'http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0
                    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
                    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
                    respData = resp.read()
                    Title = re.findall(r'e>(.*?)</title>',str(respData))
                    Title = str(Title)
                    print(Title)
                    print('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0+' ---'+Title+'---', file=open("outpute.txt", "a"))
                if i == 64:
                    i = 0
                    x += 1
"""
--------------------------------------------------------
------------------------Thread 3------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
"""
def f3(x,i,r):
    while i < 64:
                i += 1
                y = str(x)
                u0 = str(i+128)
                try:
                    t0 = urllib.request.urlopen('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0, timeout=1).getcode()
                except:
                    t0 = 'http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0+' ---NOP---'
                    print(t0)
                if t0 == 200:
                    print('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0+' ---OUI---')
                    #webbrowser.open('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u)
                    url = 'http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0
                    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
                    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
                    respData = resp.read()
                    Title = re.findall(r'e>(.*?)</title>',str(respData))
                    Title = str(Title)
                    print(Title)
                    print('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0+' ---'+Title+'---', file=open("outpute.txt", "a"))
                if i == 64:
                    i = 0
                    x += 1
"""
--------------------------------------------------------
------------------------Thread 4------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
"""
def f4(x,i,r):
    while i < 64:
                i += 1

                y = str(x)
                u0 = str(i+192)
                try:
                    t0 = urllib.request.urlopen('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0, timeout=1).getcode()
                except:
                    t0 = 'http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0+' ---NOP---'
                    print(t0)
                if t0 == 200:
                    print('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0+' ---OUI---')
                    #webbrowser.open('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u)
                    url = 'http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0
                    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
                    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
                    respData = resp.read()
                    Title = re.findall(r'e>(.*?)</title>',str(respData))
                    Title = str(Title)
                    print(Title)
                    print('http://'+r+'.'+y+'.'+u0+' ---'+Title+'---', file=open("outpute.txt", "a"))
                if i == 64:
                    i = 0
                    x += 1
"""
--------------------------------------------------------
------------------------lancement Des Threads-----------
--------------------------------------------------------
"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tr1 = Thread(target = f1, args=[x,i,r])
    tr2 = Thread(target = f2, args=[x,i,r])
    tr3 = Thread(target = f3, args=[x,i,r])
    tr4 = Thread(target = f4, args=[x,i,r])
    tr1.setDaemon(True)
    tr2.setDaemon(True)
    tr3.setDaemon(True)
    tr4.setDaemon(True)
    tr1.start()
    tr2.start()
    tr3.start()
    tr4.start()
```

Comment: Your question is not crystal. Sample I/O?

Comment: A "link" to a pastebin inside a code block inside an inline code section will not work. Create an actual [mcve] and edit that directly into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I use one function but with my threads I do this.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
tr1 = Thread(target = f1, args=[x,i,r,ztom])
tr2 = Thread(target = f1, args=[x,i+64,r,ztom])
tr3 = Thread(target = f1, args=[x,i+128,r,ztom])
tr4 = Thread(target = f1, args=[x,i+192,r,ztom])
tr1.setDaemon(True)
tr2.setDaemon(True)
tr3.setDaemon(True)
tr4.setDaemon(True)
tr1.start()
tr2.start()
tr3.start()
tr4.start()
```